# What is the distinction between different levels (rule, params, cluster config) of threads, resources and priority definition in Snakemake?

Tags: workflow, snakemake

In a Snakefile, keywords thread, priority, resources can be specified in a rule. These can also be specified as sub keywords in the params keyword. They can also be put in a shell commend as parameters or options in some application programs. Moreover, these parameters can also be specified in cluster-config if a job is submitted to a cluster.
So I am confused by these. What is the best practice? where to put these specifications? If you put these everywhere, which one is going to be effective in the system. In other words, which one has higher priority? what is the priority order?
I know there must be some reasons, I am trying to understand them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about cluster config, but regarding general snakemake usage, things defined at rule level do not have the same usage as things you would define inside a `params` section.

I would say that the most important difference is that snakemake "ignores" what is defined as part of the `params` section when deciding which rule instances should be run, while it uses things defined at rule level to decide what rules should or can be run at a given moment.

You can define whatever you want in a `params` section, and this is only used to determine the rule actions (and it is up to you to manage this in the `run` or `shell` section).

By contrast, there are a fixed list of things you can define at rule level, like `threads`, `ressources` and `priority`, and snakemake "knows" how to use them to determine what rules should be run. These things may or may not have an effect on the rule action, depending on if and how you use them.

The way to use rule-level things and `params`-defined things differ in that something defined in `params` needs to be used as attribute of the `params` object (using Python's dot syntax). `threads` defined at rule level can be used directly. This avoids ambiguities. For instance:

```
rule foo:
    # [...]
    params:
        threads=8
    threads:
        4
    shell:
        """my_command -j {params.threads} -p {threads} -i {input} -o {output}"""
```

"Rule-level" `threads` is used avoid running more rules than it should (given the total amount of "threads" you assign using the `-j` option).
Note that this doesn't actually prevent a rule action to use more threads. It all depends on the way you use (or not) the `threads` variable and how the program you are using deals with this parameter.

Rule-level `ressources` serve a similar purpose. They are taken into account by snakemake when deciding what rules to run, given the total amount provided using the `--resources` command line option. I don't know whether you can use them in the rule actions, but if it is the case, it is likely the same as with `threads`: the actual effect will depend on the program that is called, and how it is called.

Similarly, rule-level `priority` will be used by snakemake do decide what rules should be run, but has no effect in the rule action (unless there is a corresponding object available inside the `run` or `shell` section, and you use it explicitly to control something in the program you call).

To summarize:

- Rule-level things belong to a restricted set predefined by snakemake and are used automatically to control the **rule execution flow**.
- `params`-defined things can have any name, and their effect is restricted to the **rule action**. The effect depends on how you use them in the action definition (`run` or `shell`).
- Rule-level `threads` can also be used to have an effect in the rule action. Further investigation is needed regarding a possible action-level usage of `priority` or `ressources`.

Comment: Thank you, bli. I wish the snamkemake documents have more details on this and scheduling